# Dynamically import classes

Tags: python

Now i have script like this:

```
class threadEnum():
    pass

class first(threadEnum):
    pass

class second(threadEnum):
    pass

class third(threadEnum):
    pass

enums = [enum(domain, [], q=subdomains_queue, silent=silent, verbose=verbose) for enum in chosenEnums]
    for enum in enums:
        enum.start()
    for enum in enums:
        enum.join()
```

which classes is very long and takes a lot of lines. I need to move each class to separate file and then import all classes into main script. So i create folder engines and put inside three files with classes first.py, second.py and third.py also file `__init__.py`

I think must be something like that:

```
import importlib

class threadEnum():
    pass

chosenEnums = []
chosenEnums = ['first', 'second', 'third']

# Load classes from engines folder
for enumm in chosenEnums:
    module = 'engines'
    # create a global object containging our module
    mymethod = getattr(importlib.import_module('engines'), enumm)

enums = [enum(domain, [], q=subdomains_queue, silent=silent, verbose=verbose) for enum in chosenEnums]
    for enum in enums:
        enum.start()
    for enum in enums:
        enum.join()
```

But i get error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'first'

What is wrong? Python 2.7.6

Comment: Try instead of `geattr(...)` use just `mymethod = importlob.import_module('engines.' + enumm)`

Comment: You could try `__import__("{0}.{1}".format(module,enumm))`

Comment: Ok. But now i geting error `NameError: name 'threadEnum' is not defined`

Comment: Probably because you didn't define the class `threadEnum` in that file

Comment: So i need redefine in each class `threadEnum` class? Or use mutual import? But how to import from root dir from engines folder?

Comment: Better to define `threadEnum` in a separate file, and import into each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a folder as a module, the files within it are not immediately loaded as attributes.

```
>>> import importlib
>>> print(dir(importlib.import_module('engines'))

['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

To load them, you must use an `import` statement. In this case you could use `__import__("{0}.{1}".format(module,enumm))`.

Answer (score -1):

by using a simple if statement and haveing a set variable name to be the object and use the `dir()` to detect the objects within the named object (class).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your suggestion? Maybe provide a working code sample?